# Not understanding how to scan from AWB after modifing source code

Tags: c, fortify, fortify-source

My project is fairly small C project.  Running *sourceanalyzer* from a command line finishes in about 3 minutes for both translation and scan.

The documentation says if the .fpr was generated from the command line and I need to re-scan from AWB, the *Update Project Translation* button is greyed (which it is).  But if I modify the source code, the documentation says I must first update the translation before I can re-scan the code, which means I have to run *sourceanalyzer* from the command line again (since the option is greyed-out in AWB.) However, using *sourceanalyzer* re-writes the .fpr, which means I lose all my audits and custom filters that I created in AWB.

Question 1:  Can I run *sourceanalyzer* from the command line for both translation and scan without losing the audit work and custom filters I created in AWB?

The next logical step seemed to be create the .fpr from AWB.  But if I try to use AWB to start a new project using *Advanced Scan...*, it takes over an hour to complete the *Generating intermediate files - JtsWrapper.java* step.  When it's done, the results show 0 issues.

Question 2:  How do I use AWB to start a new project on a C project that doesn't use Java? When I select *Start New Project -> Advanced Scan*, it asks for the Java version.  Does that mean it thinks my project is a Java project?

This is how I use *sourceanalyzer*:

```
sourceanalyzer -clean

sourceanalyzer -64 -b myproj \
           -build-label myproj \
           -build-project myproj \
           -build-version 1.0.0 \
            touchless make -j6 -k 

sourceanalyzer -64 -b myproj \
             -build-label myproj \
             -build-project myproj \
             -build-version 1.0.0 \
             -scan \
             -f myproj.fpr
```

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1)**

There are two options for keeping your previous/existing comments, audits, and filters when creating a new scan.

a) If you scan a second time and have the -f  pointing to your existing .fpr file that has the modifications, `sourceanalyzer` will automatically merge the new results into that .fpr.

b) There is a commandline utility to merge two files together:

```
fprutility -merge -project <old.fpr> -source <new.fpr> -f <merged.fpr>
```

When you said, "The next logical step seemed to be create the .fpr from AWB."  I disagree.  Being able to produce a scan at the commandline makes the process repeatable and automatable.  AWB and the IDE plug-ins are all a front end for the `sourceanalyzer.exe`.

**Question 2)**

I am not sure what version of Fortify SCA you are using, but when I point the advanced scan at the c++ sample project (`<HPE Fortify Install Dir>/Samples/Basic/cpp`) I do not get asked about Java Versions (I am using version 16.10).

Couple of things about your commandline arguments:

- `-64` is automatically for several version now (not sure when the switch was made)
- `-build-label myproj` is optional
- `-build-project myproj` is optional
- `-build-version 1.0.0` is optional

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'm glad to know about fprutility.  Your comment in a) is inconsistent with my experience.  If I created custom filters and audit analysis for some issues in AWB, then did another scan using sourceanalyzer, then opened the new .fpr in AWB, all my previous work would be gone.

Comment: AWB Version: 4.40.0089   SCA Version:  6.40.0089

Comment: I recently discovered another option in _sourceanalyzer_ that appears to work for me.  If I add _-append_ to the scan, it keeps my previous work.    **About Question 2)** When I point my advanced scan to the same project as you did, I don't get the Java option either.  I only get it when I point it to my C folder.  I just noticed there is a folder named _Java_ in my project folder that I hadn't noticed before.  After removing that folder, I get the behavior I expect.  But it's a non-issue now, since the -append option does the trick, and as you pointed out, it's the better option.

Comment: Something seems a little off, if the `-append` option works then I am a little perplexed.  Also, when doing the `-append` option the results are no longer certified (seen on the Project Summary tab).

Comment: I don't know how it was happening before, but now it behaves as you say it should.  I can run sourceanalyzer from the command line and it no longer loses my audits.  I can't explain it, but thanks for your help.